# Issue with blit in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple platformer game in Pygame, and have created a basic outline of what I want the level to look like. However, in order to move the character around I need to continually fill the screen  with colour, which overlaps the map. How should I proceed?

My code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys

WIN_WIDTH = 680 
WIN_HEIGHT = 500 


DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT) #variable for screen display
DEPTH = 32 #standard
FLAGS = 0 #standard
RED = (0, 0, 255)

class Hero():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def appearance(self):
        return pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Player1.png')

    def move_right(self):
        self.x += 10
        return self.x


    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= 10
        return self.x





player = Hero(56, 420)
player_img = player.appearance()

x = 0
y = 0

platformx = 0
platformy = 0
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Rum Islands")
timer = pygame.time.Clock()


level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP", #45 x 25
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
        "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                     PPPPPP               P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]






pygame.key.set_repeat(10,10)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = player.move_left()


            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x = player.move_right()

    screen.fill(WHITE)            
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (platformx, platformy, 40, 20))
            platformx += 15
        platformy += 20
        platformx = 0   



    screen.blit(player_img, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: if your map fill all window (using `pygame.draw.rect()`) then you don't have to use `fill()`. So first try code without `fill(WHITE)`)

Comment: or simply use `fill(WHITE)` before you draw map - as you can see in all tutorials.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to assign `level = ...` inside `while` loop - you can do it before `while`.

Comment: I've tried using fill before I draw the map, but it still won't draw it. And i'm not sure what you meant by your first response, could you please clarify?

Comment: BTW: see how you could organize code - all drawing functions in one place - between `fill()` and `update()`, and `for events` before `fill()`: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/__template__/1__simple__.py

Comment: I edited the code in OP to match what you said and it still doesn't work, the only way the player displays correctly is if the screen fills white.

Comment: DON'T MODIFY CODE IN QUESTION !!! other people will be read it and don't understand your problem (and maybe event downvote) If you have to change something then add it i question below current text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code after modification.

Your problem was `platformy` because you never set it to zero again.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WIN_WIDTH = 680 
WIN_HEIGHT = 500 

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT) #variable for screen display
DEPTH = 32 #standard
FLAGS = 0 #standard

RED = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- classes ---

class Hero():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Player1.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += 10

    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x -= 10

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- main ---

level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP", #45 x 25
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
        "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                     PPPPPP               P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
]

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)

pygame.display.set_caption("Rum Islands")
pygame.key.set_repeat(10,10)

# - objects -

player = Hero(56, 420)

# - mainloop -

timer = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move_left()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move_right()

    # - updates -

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    platform_x = 0
    platform_y = 0

    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (platform_x, platform_y, 40, 20))
            platform_x += 15
        platform_y += 20
        platform_x = 0

    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    timer.tick(25)
```